# Get the current Menu of navigationView as R.menu

Tags: android, navigationview

In my app, I need to change the menu of the navigationView, when I click on the header 
[First state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SBtx.png) 
[Second state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i531J.png)

I wanted to get the currently active menu of my navigationView to toggle between the two menus. This is what I have written so far:

```
public void toggleMenu(){
    navigationView.getMenu().clear();
    navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_trips);
}
```

Instead of inflating the same menu all the time, I need to create an if to inflate the menu which is not currently active, something like this:

```
if (navigationView == R.menu.menu_trips){
   navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.activity_main_drawer);
} else if (navigationView == R.menu.activity_main_drawer){
   navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_trips);
}
```

**I do not want to add an MenuItem, I just want to replace the menu. Clearing it and then inflating is the best option I found.**
If you have a better solution, please tell me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not get menu id from Menu class.
I suggest you to keep a global variable that keeps your current menu id. Or you can compare first items to understand which menu is currently active.

Comment: Thank you for your quick help! I want to get the id of the current menu, not the active item of the menu. Or should I just compare the first menuItem and get, based on this, the active menu?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

```
String activeMenu;

protected void onCreate(){
    activeMenu = "main";
}

public void toggleMenu(){
    navigationView.getMenu().clear();
    if (activeMenu.equals("main")){
        navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_trips);
        activeMenu = "trips";
    } else if (activeMenu.equals("trips")){
        navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.activity_main_drawer);
        activeMenu = "main";
    }
}
```